# Bot refuses to join a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord.py refuses to join a voice channel yet does not bring up any errors when I run the command. I am rather new so have been winging it a lot yet I have looked at many things and what I have written looks right yet it still doesn't work

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')


@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  await channel.connect()
```

This I a small snippet of the code but am I right in thinking the command $join should make it join my voice channel. I have also checked on the discord developer portal that it does have permison to join voice channels.

Comment: Have you imported `from discord.ext import commands`?

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: Have you used `print` statements to see what is going wrong? It works fine for me. Can you maybe share the full code? I guess you also have an `on_message` event?

Comment: No the tutorial I am following does not say to use an on message could u please explain how to use one as I have never seen anyone use it before

Comment: in this situation

Comment: Can you please post the full code then?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have discord.py voice installed! You can do so by doing `pip install discord.py[voice]` This allows your bot to join vcs and play music.

Answer (score -2):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

# ...
```

Comment: all intents is a bit unnecessary, how about including which intents are required?

Comment: @mousetail There's no point using only the intents you need when you can use all of them.

Comment: Some intents require special permissions to use, and can cause permission errors even if you don't use them

Comment: Plus you will receive events for all your intents, which is a waste of bandwidth if you ignore them

Comment: @mousetail Permission errors don't happen with privileged intents, as the bot simply doesn't receive information about privileged intents if they aren't enabled both in the code and the Developer Portal. And receiving events for every intent? Big deal. It's miniscule compared to the enormous amount of data that normal intents (like messages) constantly send. Even better; enabling all intents saves you hassle in the future when your bot requires new ones.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or
why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I don't know how you come up with this, but you don't need intents for this. If you use a `member` argument then that makes sense, but here `ctx.author` is used (I have tested this with the intents, it works without them.). The error must be in some other part of the code. Furthermore, you did not explain how to enable the intents, nor why they are needed here.